# Как переслать ответ от пользователя Bot Telegram Api

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Я пишу бота на питоне и столкнулся с проблемой. Задача была сделать следующее: пользователь нажимает кнопку после чего другому пользователю приходит сообщение, он отвечает на него и ответ присылается обратно первому пользователю. Сообщение я отправил, только как прислать ответ обратно, заранее не зная id первого пользователя.

```
import telebot
import config
import random
from telebot import types
bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

def menu1(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Где чувак??")

    markup.add(item1)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ну и че делать?'.format(message.from_user, 
    bot.get_me()), parse_mode = 'html', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):
    sti = open('C:\stickers\sticker.webp','rb')
    bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, sti)

bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет!".format(message.from_user,bot.get_me()), 
parse_mode='html')
menu1(message)

to_chat_Id = 1188219795

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def functional(message):
    if message.chat.type =='private':
        if message.text == 'Где чувак??':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ща посмотрим...')
            bot.send_message(to_chat_Id, 'Чувак ты где?')
            #TODO
bot.polling(non_stop=True)
```